# Insertion Sort with a 2D pointer array by certain column in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Im currently struggling to implement a insertion sort algorithm for a 2D pointer array.
NO Qsort solutions please, it needs to be old school
Here is my code

```
void insertionSort(double **arr, int rows,int c)
{
    double *temp;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
        temp = *(arr+i);
        j = i - 1;

        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
          greater than key, to one position ahead
          of their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j][c] > arr[i][c]) {
            int r = j + 1;
            *(arr+r) = *(arr+j);
            j = j - 1;
        }
        int t= j + 1;
        *(arr+t) = temp;
    }
}
```

heres where i call it(rows = 3, the value 4 says which column to sort according to):

```
insertionSort(student,rows,4);
```

It needs to sort every row according to the value in the last column of each row: example : sort by column 3

input 
10 11 71
71 25 65
98 42 16

output:
98  42  16
71  25  65
10  11  71\

Any help would be appreciated since this is due this week :)

Comment: Does your code not work? What's your question?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `qsort` was added to the C programming language back in the 1970s. That makes it pretty solidly old school in my books.

Comment: You need to show the declaration of whatever you pass as the parameter `arr`. `double**` has absolutely nothing to do with an array. It is a single pointer to an allocated block of pointers each of which in turn point to allocated blocks of `double`. If that is not what you have --- there is no wonder it doesn't work. Your pointer arithmetic will be fried. (you may want to choose type `int` for the return so you can indicate success or failure to the caller -- up to you)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming `arr` is an allocated block of pointers where each pointer holds the address of an allocated block of `double`, you simply need to compare by the last column in each block of `double` and swap pointers in `arr` to sort. Your `insertionSort()` function can be reduced to:

```c
void insertionSort (double **arr, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) /* insertion sort of a by last col */
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && arr[j][cols-1] < arr[j-1][cols-1]; j--) {
            double *tmp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            arr[j-1] = tmp;
        }
}
```

(**note:** `c` has been changed to `cols`)

This will not work with a 2D array. With a 2D array you must save and copy rows instead of pointers with a loop or `memcpy()`. This all presumes your `double **arr` is correct and you have allocated pointers and allocated blocks for the `double` and are now sorting be the last `double` in each row of `arr`. An example would be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insertionSort (double **arr, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) /* insertion sort of a by last col */
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && arr[j][cols-1] < arr[j-1][cols-1]; j--) {
            double *tmp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            arr[j-1] = tmp;
        }
}

void prnrowscols (size_t rows, size_t cols, double **arr)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf (j ? " %4g" : "%4g", arr[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    double tmp[][3] = { {10, 11, 71},
                        {71, 25, 65},
                        {98, 42, 16} },
           **arr = NULL;
    size_t  rows = sizeof tmp / sizeof *tmp,
            cols = sizeof *tmp / sizeof **tmp;
    
    if (!(arr = malloc (rows * sizeof *arr))) {
        perror ("malloc-arr");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (!(arr[i] = malloc (cols * sizeof *arr[i]))) {
            perror ("malloc-arr[i]");
            return 1;
        }
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            arr[i][j] = tmp[i][j];
    }
    
    puts ("orignal array:");
    prnrowscols (rows, cols, arr);
    
    insertionSort (arr, rows, cols);
    
    puts ("\nsorted array:");
    prnrowscols (rows, cols, arr);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)       /* free memory */
        free (arr[i]);
    free (arr);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/inssort_ptr2ptr
orignal array:
  10   11   71
  71   25   65
  98   42   16

sorted array:
  98   42   16
  71   25   65
  10   11   71
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer to my question, just had to point to the c column using pointers in my while loop as a comparable(instead of arr[i][c] it became *(temp+c):

```
void insertionSort(double **arr, int rows,int c)
{
    double *temp;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
        temp = *(arr+i);
        j = i - 1;

        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
          greater than key, to one position ahead
          of their current position */
        
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j][c] > *(temp+c) ) {
            int r = j + 1;
            *(arr+r) = *(arr+j);
            j = j - 1;
        }
        int t= j + 1;
        *(arr+t) = temp;
    }
}
```

tx for help everyone